# BigQuery get all values in a range

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a column that can contains a range and I want to get all values in that range. I.e

I have the following records

```
id | number
-------------
1  | 342-345
-------------
2  | 346
```

And a want it in the following format:

```
id | number
-------------
1  | 342
   | 343
   | 344
   | 345
-------------
2  | 346
```

I am using Standard SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `split()` to split the string and then `generate_array()` to get the values you want:

```
select t.*,
       GENERATE_ARRAY(cast(split(numbers, '-')[ordinal(1)] as int64),
                      cast(COALESCE(split(numbers, '-')[SAFE_ORDINAL(2)], split(numbers, '-')[ordinal(1)]) as int64),
                      1)
from (select 1 as id, '342-345' as numbers UNION ALL
      SELECT 2, '346'
     ) t;
```